# python sphinx autodoc exclude __init__

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have 2 classes.
Class1 needs to display all docstrings,
while Class2 needs to display only method docstrings.
In the following example, I am trying to disable Class2 without success,
docstrings of Class2 still displayed.
Please help me disable class and init docstrings in Class2.

conf.py

```py
autoclass_content = "both"
```

index.rst

```
Title
=====

.. autoclass:: classes.Class1
  :members:

.. autoclass:: classes.Class2
  :members: method
  :exclude-members: __init__, __weakref__
```

classes.py

```py
class Class1:
    """Docstring1"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init1"""

    def method(self):
        """Method1"""


class Class2:
    """Docstring2"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init2"""

    def method(self):
        """Method2"""
```

expected result

```
Title

class classes.Class1
    Docstring1
    Init1

    method()
        Method1

class classes.Class2

    method()
        Method2
```

actual result

```
Title

class classes.Class1
    Docstring1
    Init1

    method()
        Method1

class classes.Class2
    Docstring2
    Init2

    method()
        Method2
```